# XMPPError: item-not-found - cancel

Tags: android, android-studio, xampp, openfire, multiuserchat

I am using **xampp and Openfire** for group chat in android. I have attached my code below which is used to join a chat room but I was getting an error saying **XMPPError: item-not-found - cancel**.

Though I have tried some relevant questions none of those answers helped me out. So if anyone can help me with that then it would be great.

```
public void joinChatRoom(String userName, String roomName) {
    try {
        Log.d("xmpp: ", "Service Name: " + connection.getServiceName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("xmpp: ", "service name error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    multiUserChat = manager.getMultiUserChat(roomName+ "@" +CHAT_ROOM_SERVICE_NAME + CHAT_SERVER_SERVICE_NAME);
    try {
        multiUserChat.join(userName);
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("xmpp: ", "Chat room join Error: " + e.getMessage());
        sendBroadCast("joinerror", e.getMessage());
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("xmpp: ", "Chat room join Error: " + e.getMessage());
        sendBroadCast("joinerror", e.getMessage());
    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("xmpp: ", "Chat room join Error: " + e.getMessage());
        sendBroadCast("joinerror", e.getMessage());
    }

    // if user joined successfully
    if (multiUserChat.isJoined()) {
        Log.d("xmpp: ", "user has Joined in the chat room");
        sendBroadCast("join", "done");
        //call method to configure room
        configRoom(roomName);

        // get Roster
        getBuddies();
        //get user info
        getUserInfo(userName);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I just updated my Chat object. The imported class was wrong previously.
Now it's corrected with the following line.

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat
```